# Stop awarding rep for asking questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions

It kills me seeing questions that could be easily answered searching, and I wonder why the person is asking if searching in Google or SO is **less** effort than writing a question.

The answer must be: **To gain rep.** For example [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68183/mrblah) got 8.800 rep only by asking, not one answer.

Maybe if we stop awarding rep on questions people will no longer post silly questions, and, having an answer should be enough motivator if your question is real.

Maybe it's a little drastic, but something must be done. The site is full of crap now.

Comment: Someday I'll figure out who has a vendetta against me or maybe its just a vendetta against reason.  Or maybe they deleted my answer to give me some rep back.

Comment: @ChrisGerken Hmm? Your answer isn't deleted. But it does seem that a few people disagree with your proposition.

Comment: Silly questions tend to get downvotes anyway... why would we not want to reward *good* questions?

Comment: a duplicate of [Could we put a cap on reputation earned by asking questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81911/165773). Also related / duplicates: [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/165773), and, of course, [Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56817/165773), with 50+ questions currently linked to last one

Answer (score 13):

So, aside from focusing on the raw reputation, how many of that user's questions would you say are really bad?

What about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010284/equivalent-of-datetime-now-in-java), for example? 68 upvotes, 75,000+ views, a solid answer. People searching for this "silly" question now find a helpful answer on Stack Overflow.

Don't forget that without folks asking questions, there would be nothing for the rest of us to answer.

Let's also not forget that the flip side to gaining reputation from asking questions is losing reputation from asking questions that are poorly researched or not useful. [Question downvotes are free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free), so by all means use them when you see questions that you think aren't good enough and can't be improved with a well-placed edit.

Comment: I'm ok with the upvotes, only refers to the rep. And I'm ok with people asking questions, but, the are too many dups or basic or silly questions that cant find the motivator (other than rep) for people posting them

Comment: It shows that downvotes are free. I've got 7 of them :)

Comment: @EduardoMolteni The motivator is probably a lot simpler: either inability or unwillingness to search. Really basic questions don't tend to get the greatest reception on SO these days. (And for what it's worth, [downvotes on meta often just imply disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).)

Comment: @EduardoMolteni: 8, I up voted you

Answer (score -7):

Nah, I say game the gamers...

- Limit the total rep awarded for your questions to the total rep awarded for your answers
- If a question is closed for any reason, the OP should lose rep equal to 10 + the total rep already awarded for any answers

Comment: Your first bullet might be viable, but penalties for downvoting questions were removed some time ago, and I see plenty of downvotes on many closed questions, so I don't think you need to encourage any more rep loss.