# What is the purpose of Stack Overflow reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

It sounds a little silly, but I used to think that when I ask a question and get an answer by a member with high reputation, that reputation actually represents a lot of knowledge, experience, etc.. But I found out that many members have a **huge** reputation just because they asked **very basic** questions
(some of them got 800 votes and more for 1 question.), while at the same time contributed less than 5 answers which got hardly 1 or 2 votes.

On the other hand, a lot of people spend time and efforts to answer questions (sometimes very good answers) and get only few votes , if any.

I think that every question/answer should be restricted to something like 10 votes max, but until then:

What is the purpose of Stack Overflow reputation (by its current score system )?

**This is not a duplicated question. I know how reputaion works (how much reputation you get for each action/vote ...) I just don't understand the purpose of it (through its current score system that doesn't restrict the number of votes one could get for simple question/ or answer...)**

Comment: Or: "What is the purpose of reputation on meta stackoverflow?"

Comment: Seems this question could get many votes, and that in turn should bring you a lot of reputation. Was that the plan? ;-)

Comment: please stop voting up this question. it is not my intention!

Comment: I was just kidding, don't worry.

Comment: Also the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) describes it pretty well. *Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you*, not as you put it *a representation a lot of knowledge, experience*

Comment: so you suggest that if one is asking how to check if string contains a substring , and this person get 800 votes for that question- does this mean that the cummunity trust him?

Comment: @yoav welcome to Meta! You're asking the right questions. :) This is actually a long discussion, see e.g. [Do some users have too much rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70991) there's plenty of things one *could* do to address the issue, and much has been done, but the general consensus is that being too radical in trying to fix this would do a lot of damage elsewhere.